# How can I set the non-response time on CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION?

Tags: php, curl

There is an ip that constantly (every 5 seconds), responds as a stream. This is the camera that informs about new videos. The writer function maintains these responses and the handler handles the response. I need this request to run forever, but at some point, like now for example, the camera may stop responding altogether. The lights are off or something else happens, but now I can't access the ip. In normal state the camera is always responding:

```
--myboundary
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 9
Heartbeat
```

Which means that there are no new videos. At this point I have logged the last time and the response when writer started and that's it.

How can I set some kind of limiter so that it triggers if there is no response within 20 seconds? Essentially, TIMEOUT is responsible for this, but the script will stop running after 20 seconds even if there was a response in writer, so it is currently set to 0. We need another limiter.

```
function writer($ch, $data) {
  handler($data);
  return strlen($data);
}

$ch = curl_init("$urlcam/cgi-bin/eventManager.cgi?action=attach&codes=[NewFile]&heartbeat=5");
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => "$user:$pass",
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 20,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH=>CURLAUTH_DIGEST,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION => 'writer'
    ]);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```